# How to add sub-select to select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I want to execute a query like this:

```sql
SELECT Table1.COL1,
       Table1.COL2,
       (SELECT SUM(Table2.COL3)
          FROM Table2
         WHERE Table2.UID = Table1.UID) SUMOF
  FROM Table1;
```

How can I do it?
I usually create a `Criteria` add `ProjectionList` to it, to fill `COL1` and `COL2` only.
I have created a `DetachedCriteria` to calculate the `sum`...

Now, how to attach this detached criteria to the main one? My intuition says - it's some sort of Projection which needs to be added to the list, but I don't see how.  Also, not sure how `WHERE Table2.COL4 = Table1.COL5` of detached criteria will work.

Also, I'm sure this query might be written in different way, for example with join statement. It's still interesting if there's a way to run it like this.

### `DetachedCriteria` and main `Criteria`

```java
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table2.class, "table2");
detachedCriteria
  .setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.sum("table2.col3"), "sumCol3")
  )
  .add(Restrictions.eq("table2.uid", "table1.uid"))
;

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Table1.class, "Table1");
criteria
  .setProjection(
    Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("Table1.col1"), "col1")
      .add(Projections.property("Table1.col2"), "col2")
  )
;
```

### Entities (very short version)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
public class Table1 {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "uid")
  public String getUid();

  @Column(name = "col1")
  public String getCol1();

  @Column(name = "col2")
  public String getCol2();

  @Column(name = "col3")
  public String getCol3();

  @Column(name = "col4")
  public String getCol4();

  @Column(name = "col5")
  public String getCol5();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Table2")
public class Table2 {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "uid")
  public String getUid();

  @Column(name = "col3")
  public BigDecimal getCol3();

  @Column(name = "col4")
  public String getCol4();

  @Column(name = "col5")
  public String getCol5();
}
```

Comment: Care to tell us what is "DetachedCriteria" and "Projection" ? They are not JPA classes. If using JPQL then you will have to tell people what entities/fields you have, since tables are of no relevance there.

Comment: Why not just run the SQL statement? Your solution is at the beginning of your question

Comment: @LukasEder Currently, in our system we do use SQL only statements to present a list of data stored in DB (only for viewing). I'm investigating the possibilities of using pure Java, without the need to write queries. The example above is just a very uncommon case we usually have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a correlated subquery (like the one you presented above), you can use [@Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula) which can take an arbitrary SQL query. Then, you'll need to fetch the entity and the subquery will be executed.

However, a native SQL is more elegant if you only need this query for a single business requirement.

As for derived table queries (e.g. select from select), neither JPA nor Hibernate support derived table queries for a very good reason.

Entity queries (JPQL pr Criteria) are meant to fetch entities that you plan to modify.

For a derived table projection, native SQL is the way to go. Otherwise, why do you think EntityManager offers a createNativeQuery method?